# Copying Data from table to another table and applying one to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel

This is my Report Model

```
protected $fillable = [
    'site_url',
    'reciepients',
    'monthly_email_date'
];

public function site()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Site');
}
```

This is my Site Model

```
public function report()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Report');
}
```

This is my ReportController

```
public function showSpecificSite($site_name)
{

$records = DB::table('reports')
          ->select('email_date','url','recipient') 
          ->whereHas('sites', function($query){
                    $query->where('site_name',$site_name);
           })
          ->get();

  return view('newsite')->with('records',$records)
  ->with('site_name',$site_name);
}
```

My Controller is not yet working as well.
The thing is I would like to copy all the three files from sites table to reports table.

Is it possible in `insertInto` ?

My code on ReportController shows you that I'm selecting data from reports table but I am the one who puts data to reports table to see the output but it is not yet working because of the it cant reach out the value of *site_name* even though I already put a relationship between the two tables.

Comment: Looks like `$site_name` is not defined in the callback function scope, try `function($query) use ($site_name) {`

Comment: @Havenard tried already but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not actually using Eloquent in your controller you're just using the Query Builder (`DB`). This will mean that you don't have access to anything from your Eloquent models.

Try:

```
$records = \App\Report::whereHas('site', function($query) use($site_name) {
        $query->where('site_name', $site_name);
    })->get(['id', 'email_date', 'url', 'recipient']);
```

I've added `id` to the list of columns as I'm pretty sure you'll need that to use `whereHas`.

**NB** to use a variable from the parent scope inside a closure you need to pass it in using `use()`.

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sites() 
whereHas(); function was not working too

Comment: @Christian Sorry, I should have noticed that. The method you have in your `Report` model is called `site`, however, with the query in your question it was down as `sites`. It should match the method name you have in your model. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ross Wilson